# generate key for licensing purposes

Tags: cpu, background-process

I am interested to know if there is a way to allow a user of a web application to log in the application in the following way:

1) Generate a unique key (for licensing purposes) based on unique numbers of the device (motherboard, BIOS, HDD ...)
2) save it in db (sign up)
3) log in, ONLY from the registered device, with a button on the desktop,
without knowing the generated password.

If there is any   ready made sorftware / code / links to study / opinions over the implementation .... would be helpful.

Thanx

Comment: You should not limit access to one device, or a replaceable hardware component of that device (like HDD), because if one replaces that, he loses access.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is not possible. For obvious security reasons, the code executed by a browser can **not** access system hardware. Perhaps it might be possible with a Java applet, but the user would probably be reluctant to run an applet.

Why do not I think of a cookie?

Comment: should this java applet be executed every time the user logs in?Thanx

Comment: If you must check each time system data to validate the license then the answer is yes. But in my opinion is not the way most correct. It would be better, perhaps, use a cookie that is issued by the server in response to the proper registration of the product and that has a expiry of one year for example.